# Android Save Spinner Selection

Tags: android, android-intent, spinner, sharedpreferences, commit

I have two activities. In the second activity I have a `spinner`. what I would like to happen is after the user selects an item from the spinner it will save via `actionbar` press and on back press which will load the previous activity. Based on my research my activity is supposed to look something like the following below but it's not working what am I doing wrong??

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    spin = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.editspin);

    Intent i = this.getIntent();
    note = new ArgueItem();
    note.setKey(i.getStringExtra("key"));
    note.setText(i.getStringExtra("text"));

    EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.argueEdit);
    et.setText(note.getText());
    et.setSelection(note.getText().length());


}private boolean saveState() {
          prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
          SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = prefs.edit();
          int daddy = spin.getSelectedItemPosition();
          prefEditor.putInt("savedValue",daddy);
          prefEditor.commit();
        return true;
    }

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.argueEdit);
    String argueText = et.getText().toString();
    if(argueText.equals("")){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enter A New ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return false;
    }
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        saveAndFinish();
    }
    return false;
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.argueEdit);
    String argueText = et.getText().toString();
    if(argueText.equals("")){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enter A New ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return;
    }else{
    saveAndFinish();
}
```

Comment: post your activity class - you only posted a helper class - how it's used ? _What does not work_ ?? Where is the `spin` field set ?

Comment: it is normal java class

Comment: post ur activity class

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D I've updated my code to the activity

Comment: @ShakeebAyaz I've updated my code to the activity

Answer (score 0):

In your second activity, you have to override the `onPause()` and. Inside it write the saving process.

```
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();

    //Include the code which, save the data.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a FragmentActivity and add/remove fragments within the same activity.
check these resources:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html

Answer (score 0):

This is how i'm initializing my spinner which is in the `ActionBar`. I'm not adding it as a custom view, but I'm using the drop down menu feature.

```
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, new ActionBar.OnNavigationListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {

            //save in preferences
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this).edit().
                    putInt(SELECTED_DIARY_PREF, itemPosition).commit();

            return true;
        }
    });
int selPosition = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getInt(SELECTED_DIARY_PREF, 0);
actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(selPosition);
```

What this code does is: saving the preference when an item of the menu is clicked, and restoring that preference when the activity is launched. Hope it helps.