# Save Current Day to TextView using Shared Preferences

Tags: android, android-listview, sharedpreferences

I want to save the current date to a textview within my listview I have everything else setup so no need for help there just saving date to textview my code is as follows can someone tell me what wrong?

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    long millis = date.getTime();
    SharedPreferences prefs =
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putLong("time", date.getTime());
    editor.commit();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/y H:m");
    String biggie = sdf.format(date);
    Date myDate = new Date(prefs.getLong("time", 0));
    holder.day.setText();

    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflator =
            (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);          
      } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.gump.setText(argueList.get(position));
}
```

Comment: You've asked 3 questions already I read and never bothered to accept an answer - or post one yourself - consider this a warning

Comment: Also _format the code you post_ - heck what you posted even misses braces !

Comment: a warning??? @Mr_and_Mrs_D because the answers are not helping or what I'm looking for and i have posted answers dont make this a bigger issue than it is

Comment: Posting a question after another without trying to answer the previous one is bad practice for stackoverflow - and if the answers do not help maybe the fault is in the question - look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20726123/android-save-spinner-selection#comment31091306_20726123. That's wasting people's time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of points to be made here.
First of all, the `getView` method in the array adapter is called when the system draws each element in the list. It is bad practice to create any variables in there, because it will be doing it over and over again, quickly wasting memory and forcing the garbage collector to run. So first of all, move all the initialization out of the method.

Second, it's unclear what you are trying to do here. If you just want to display the date on each entry if the `listview`, just get the date as a string (outside of the getview method - the date is unlikely to change while the user is looking at the view) and set the text to the dateString at the end of the `getView`.

If this is all you want to do, you don't need the preferences here at all...

Can you give more info as to what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I would like the current date to be set to a textview for each listview entry (Much like a note taking app) example: if i type "Apple" in my edittext and add it to my listview  via onClick I want "Aplle" with 12/24/2013 next to it. Tomorrow when I add "Grape" i want that entry to say 12/25/2013. Keeping both entries with different dates

Comment: sounds like your best option is to use a database. store the note and timestamp in the table and the query the table when drawing the view